# React SSR two pass rendering with renderToString and renderToNodeStream

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, server-side-rendering, react-helmet

I'm trying to do SSR with `ReactDOMServer.renderToNodeStream(element)` but just wanted to know if there would be any problem with using both `ReactDOMServer.renderToString(element)` and  `ReactDOMServer.renderToNodeStream(element)` at each request?

What I have in my custom SSR setup is:
* React 16
* react-loadable
* styled-components v4
* react-helmet-async
* Redux
* Express JS

Previously with React, I could easily render a HTML document by first rendering the `<head></head>` tags that contains markup produced by `react-helmet` and then using `ReactDOMServer.renderToString()` to render my React elements.

However, by switching to `ReactDOMServer.renderToNodeStream()` I had to switch `react-helmet` for `react-helmet-async`, which supports `renderToNodeStream()` function. But then when I try to render the `<head></head>` tags with the markup by `react-helmet-async` it'll come back as `undefined`.

To get around this problem, I've had to use `renderToString()` first without actually writing that out to Express JS `response`. That way `react-helmet-async` can then see what meta tags to render and then proceed to use `renderToNodeStream` and stream that out to the `response`.

I've simplified my code as much as possible as I want to understand if this would have a negative impact (for performance, or if anyone can think of anything else)?

Before:

```
let html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(stylesheet.collectStyles(
    <Loadable.Capture report={moduleName => modules.push(moduleName)}>
        <LocalStoreProvider store={store}>
            <HelmetProvider context={helmetContext}>
                <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
            </HelmetProvider>
        </LocalStoreProvider>
    </Loadable.Capture>
));

const { helmet } = helmetContext; 

response.write(
    renderDocumentHead({
        css: stylesheet.getStyleTags(),
        title: helmet.title.toString(),
        link: helmet.link.toString(),
        meta: helmet.meta.toString()
    })
);

response.write(html);
```

After:

```
let html = stylesheet.collectStyles(
    <Loadable.Capture report={moduleName => modules.push(moduleName)}>
        <LocalStoreProvider store={store}>
            <HelmetProvider context={helmetContext}>
                <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
            </HelmetProvider>
        </LocalStoreProvider>
    </Loadable.Capture>
);

// do a first pass render so that react-helmet-async 
// can see what meta tags to render
ReactDOMServer.renderToString(html);

const { helmet } = helmetContext; 

response.write(
    renderDocumentHead({
        css: stylesheet.getStyleTags(),
        title: helmet.title.toString(),
        link: helmet.link.toString(),
        meta: helmet.meta.toString()
    })
);

const stream = stylesheet.interleaveWithNodeStream(
    ReactDOMServer.renderToNodeStream(html)
);

// and then actually stream the react elements out
stream.pipe(response, { end: false });

stream.on('end', () => response.end('</body></html>'));
```

Unfortunately, the only way I could get `react-helmet-async` to work correctly, I have to do this two-pass render. My CSS styles, etc. resolves correctly and the client renders/hydrates correctly too. I've seen other examples where `react-apollo` was used and the `getDataFromTree` data rehydration method was used which allows `react-helmet-async` to see what was needed to render the head markup. But hopefully there are no issues with my two-pass rendering approach?

Comment: I arrived at the same conclusion. I tried using `react-tree-walker` to have a cheaper option

but couldn't get it to work. Tried a number of scenarios

Comment: Yeah I think I've come to the conclusion that there's no issues with doing this as it's just running a function, not storing it anywhere or outputting via the response. I few other resources also mention a two pass render to make this work. I think if your custom SSR approach allows for this then this is a possible solution.

Comment: @S.Luong Does reach-helmet-async help me to get dynamic meta data in SSR at first hit and not undefined?

Comment: Never seen or used reach-helmet-async but react-helmet-async won't help you on first hit as far as I last checked.

Comment: Really interesting solution to this problem. I've recently been trying to migrate over to `renderToNodeStream` myself and have been encountering that my dynamic (i.e. depends on API data) helmet head data was out of sync. 

I also found this thread of interest over on react-helmet-async issues and the author had this tidbit to say: https://github.com/staylor/react-helmet-async/issues/37#issuecomment-622530358

A suggestion made by the user "diondirza" has gotten me closer to solving this issue. I still have to figure out how to properly transform the data stream.

Comment: Your scenario is very similar to mine in that case where my dynamic helmet data also depends on API data. My rationale for trying out `renderToNodeStream` was to improve my TTFB time and overall performance. So when you start processing your route matching you would do a `response.write` html fragment right at the beginning. But then comes your async actions of waiting for a response from your API. Is it going to be ~300ms? Because then you're just losing out on some serious time. Probably better to serve a cached HTML response if possible

Comment: Also for my tech stack, I found that from my node server, via a reverse proxy, through to AWS CloudFront I get ~300ms TTFB with ~11ms content download. But with a cached html response I can bring the TTFB down to ~60ms. However, in this yet another experimental solution I haven't figured out the the problem of state management and not just caching the response for one user.

Comment: I thought `renderToNodeStream` exist beacause it can make renderering process to readable stream, so send response  without wating all rendering process.

If you render your contents with `renderToString`, isn't there no advantage to using `renderToNodeStream`?

Comment: Yep ideally it's use one or the other. There are advantages to using `renderToNodeStream` and you certainly should be using that, if possible. In my scenario, I can't use it as I would need another workaround to generate my html meta tags.